# Font Awesome Icons not working on Chrome App

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension, font-awesome, google-chrome-app

I'm making a chrome app which uses icon icon-calendar as well as fa fa-chevron-right.

When i live preview my app in a browser the fa fa-chevron icon works, but not the icon icon-calendar. Currently they are just showing as white boxes.

When i launch my app via the extension thing on chrome, BOTH the fa and icon don't work.

I have the icons.css file in my folder, as well as these in my header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="icons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Do i need to give permission to FontAwesome in my manifest file or something like that?

HTML:

```
<a>
<span class="icon icon-calendar"></span>
<span class="title">Book A Table</span>
</a>
<li>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</li>
```

Comment: Does your `icons.css` have a `.icon-calendar`?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome apps are subject to the following [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy):

```
default-src 'self';
connect-src * data: blob: filesystem:;
style-src 'self' data: chrome-extension-resource: 'unsafe-inline';
img-src 'self' data: chrome-extension-resource:;
frame-src 'self' data: chrome-extension-resource:;
font-src 'self' data: chrome-extension-resource:;
media-src * data: blob: filesystem:;
```

This means you cannot load a CSS file from an external source, and that CSS file cannot load icons themselves from an external source.

There is no way to relax this policy. In some cases you can work around it by [explicitly downloading resources](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#external) and serving them as `blob:` URLs, but that's really not going to reasonably work for FA.

You need to [download a local version of FA](http://fontawesome.io/get-started/#get-started-download) instead of using the CDN-provided one.

Comment: So whats the name of the file that i need to put it my folder then? If i cant use icons.css...

Comment: It has nothing to do with `icons.css`: why that doesn't work we cannot guess without seeing the file. I'm talking about `font-awesome.min.css`. You need the `css` and `fonts` folders from the download version of FA in your app (possibly only parts of them).